# Fazer ancora em AngularJS

Tags: html, angularjs, aplicação-web

Olá, eu preciso criar uma âncora em que quando eu clico em um link ele seta display block em uma div escondida e desça a página até essa div. A parte de dar display block eu já fiz, o que eu preciso é a parte em que eu clique no link e a página desça. Estou usando Angular, então eu não posso usar #id_div para isso. Alguém tem alguma ideia?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá, consegui resolver esse problema da seguinte maneira: no link, eu coloco um scrollTo com o id da div que ele deverá ir:

```
<a href="" ng-click="vm.scrollTo('box')">
```

na div eu colocolo o id dele normal né:

```
<div id="box" class="col-md-12">
```

Já no controller da minha página, é necessário colocar uma função para ele rolar para baixo, que no meu caso ficou:

```
vm.scrollTo = function (id) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $location.hash(id);
            $anchorScroll();
        }, 100);
    };
```

Eu coloquei o set timeout porque acontecia de eu ter que clicar 2 ou 3 vezes no link para ele conseguir descer a página, dessa forma o bug é resolvido

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar um `target="_self"` no seu `href`. Isso vai impedir a ação por parte do `angularjs`:

```
<a href="#teste" target="_self"></a>
<div id="teste"></div>
```